# LibGdx Box2dLights: How to make Chain Lights emit light in all directions?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, box2dlights

The "ChainLight" Class has a parameter in its constructor which is called "rayDirection":

ChainLight(rayHandler, rays, Color, distance, **rayDirection**, float[] vertices)

Apparently, if it is set to "1", the light direction is left and if it is "-1", the light direction is right.

Question: Is there a way to make it emit light in **ALL** directions (including up and down) without creating new instances?

Comment: Any image of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ChainLight is intended to allow you to build arbitrary shapes with light emitting out from them.

The direction of left or right ( 1 or -1 ) will be determined by which direction you define your vertices in, So you could define a chain like so:

```
v2(0,1)______________v3(1,1)
     |               |
     |               |   
     |               |
v1(0,0)v5(0,0)_______v4(1,0)
```

Hopefully my ascii art is clear enough. We have a chain made up of 4 lines defined by 5 coordinates (1 and 5 are the same coordinates to create a closed shape). And because the vertices wind around in a clockwise direction, the direction of the light should be left - I think - to make the light shine outwards rather than inwards. Give it a try.

This hopefully gives you the left, right, up and down kind of thing you are looking for.

Comment: Very well explained.